# Finding the numerically lowest line in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I'm working on a guessing game written in Python, where the user guesses a number in a certain range (1-1000), and the high scores (lowest number of tries) are appended to a text file.

I need to find a way to read through all of the numbers, and print (read) the lowest value to the screen. Is there an easy way to do this? I've been running into issues thus far. Here's a portion of my code:

```
if guess == the_number:
        print "--------------------------------------"
        print "You guessed correctly! The number was:", the_number
        print "And it only took you", no_of_tries, "tries!"
        text_file = open("scores.txt", "a")
        the_scores = text_file.write(str(no_of_tries) + ' ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have all scores seperated by spaces, then you can retrive them by this method

```
input=open('scores.txt')
scores=input.read()
scores=scores.split()
print min(scores)
```

to print the minimum guess